# AWS cloudfront - why my assets appear twice in page speed tests?

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

Here is an example: http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/#!/cp0wwy/http://www.shearcomfort.com/Car-Seat-Covers_CDN.asp

Pick any image, say `2014_subaru_outback_mini.jpg` then you can see it appears twice: once from cloudfront with 0 bytes and the second time from the actual domain `shearcomfort.com`

Can anyone explain what is going on here and how to make all the assets come only from cloudfront and not from the home domain?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your CDN URLs are returning 301 Redirects.

`curl -I http://d3cerlni7xmxaw.cloudfront.net/images/stars/images/2starrating.gif`

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 186
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://www.shearcomfort.com/images/stars/images/2starrating.gif
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 20 May 2014 17:43:02 GMT
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 45f9deebd67d2bd40b8384feda6e6e32.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: dcbTEOwj48JfPD8YrvKrk4m2-OCkCAAABdqnwGxBOfRkmdLLpl7ErQ==
```

I'd bet you pointed your CloudFront distribution at `shearcomfort.com` rather than `www.shearcomfort.com`. You appear to 301 URLs on that domain to the www version.

Comment: Thank you, been bashing my head against the desk on this one

Answer (score 2):

The 301 Moved Permanently can also happen if you're running a https only site and 301 redirect http visitors to https (and therefore also cloudfront).

There is a setting under origin in cloudfront "Origin Protocol Policy" make sure this is set to "Match Viewer" so that cloudfront requests the https version from your origin server and not http (as is default).